# Create FCM Device Group returns 401

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to create a FCM device group for one of my users, but when posting the `create` request I get `401 reponse code` :

Here is my `POST` request:

```
if let url = URL(string: "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/notification") {
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.addValue(apiKey, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        request.addValue(senderId, forHTTPHeaderField: "project_id")

        let registration_ids = [deviceToken] as! [String]
        let jsonToSend = ["operation": "create",
                          "notification_key_name": LocalUser.shared.firebaseId,
                          "registration_ids": registration_ids
            ] as [String : Any]

        do {
            let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonToSend, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
            request.httpBody = jsonData

            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
                if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
                    print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                    print("response = \(response.debugDescription)")
                } else if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse {

                    print("statusCode is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                    print("response = \(response.debugDescription)")

                }
            }
            task.resume()
        } catch {
            print("could not serialize json")
        }
    }
```

Also do you know what will happen if I try to create a `device group` with an already existing `notification_key_name`. Will the new `device key` be added to the existing group? Or is there a way to check if a group exists ?

Comment: Is this being done client side or on a server? It has to be done via a server.

Comment: it is done client side ... should i do it using cloud functions instead ? also what is wrong with doing it client side ?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/device-group - "Basic management of device groups — creating and removing groups, and adding or removing devices — is usually performed via the app server. See the HTTP protocol reference for a list of supported keys.
Optionally, Android client apps can manage device groups from the client side."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this statement:

```
request.addValue(apiKey, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
```

`apiKey` must be the Server Key from your project settings, prefixed by `key=`. 
 For example: `key=AAAPWK_CVGw:APA91b...saklHTO29fTk`

You indicate in a comment that you are doing this from a client device.  Putting your Server Key in device code is not safe.

A safer alternative is to perform the device group creation in a Cloud Function.  Below is a basic implementation triggered by storing the group creation parameters in the database.  Example only; not thoroughly tested; corrections/comments welcome.

```
const rqstProm = require('request-promise');

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.createDeviceGroup = functions.database.ref("/deviceGroup/create/params")
       .onWrite(event => {
    const serverKey = 'AAAAXp6june:APA91bF-Nq9pm...3dD5pZxVsNBfX0O3_Xf-jV472nfn-sb';
    const senderId = '271828182845';
    // TODO add checks for valid request params
    const request = event.data.val();
    const groupName = request.groupName;
    const tokens = Object.keys(request.tokens);

    console.log('groupName=', groupName, 'tokens=', tokens.length);

    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        uri: 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/notification',
        headers: {
           'Authorization': 'key=' + serverKey,
           'project_id': senderId
        },
        body: {
           operation: 'create',
           notification_key_name: groupName,
           registration_ids: tokens
        },
        json: true
    };

    const resultRef = admin.database().ref('deviceGroup/create/result/key');

    return rqstProm(options)
        .then((parsedBody) => {
            console.log('SUCCESS response=', parsedBody);
            return resultRef.set(parsedBody.notification_key);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log('FAILED err=', err);
            return resultRef.set('ERROR: ' + err);
        });
});
```

Sample code (Android) for creating a device group using the Cloud Function:

```
private ValueEventListener resultListener;

private void createDeviceGroup(String groupName, String ...deviceTokens) {
    final DatabaseReference baseRef =
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("deviceGroup/create");

    final DatabaseReference resultRef = baseRef.child("result");

    // listener to get the result of the group creation request
    resultListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snap) {
            if (snap.exists()) {
                // got the result; stop listening
                resultRef.removeEventListener(resultListener);
                String key = snap.child("key").getValue(String.class);
                Log.d(TAG, "createDeviceGroup: key=" + key);
            } else {
                // we get here when listener is first attached
                Log.w(TAG, "createDeviceGroup: No Result");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            resultRef.removeEventListener(resultListener);
            throw databaseError.toException();
        }
    };

    // remove any previous result
    resultRef.removeValue();
    // start listening for a result
    resultRef.addValueEventListener(resultListener);

    // build the request params
    final Map<String,Object> request = new HashMap<>();
    final Map<String,Object> tokens = new HashMap<>();
    // creation of device group requires a name and set of tokens
    request.put("groupName", groupName);
    request.put("tokens", tokens);

    for (String token : deviceTokens) {
        // tokens are stored as keys; value is not significant
        tokens.put(token, true);
    }
    // write the request; this triggers Cloud Function to create device group
    baseRef.child("params").setValue(request);
}
```

This is the database layout after a successful group creation:

```
{
  "deviceGroup": {
    "create": {
      "params": {
        "groupName": "testGroupA",
        "tokens": {
          "ccVDiSO1tbc:APA91bE3pELSz...oDqY_ioLRj4xUnk5mci6ateFRVe" : true,
          "pqUYfyTbuax:APA91bE3pELSz...oDqY_ioLRj4xUnk5mci6ateFRVe" : true,
          "tyKUY1mrUR8:APA91bE3pELSz...oDqY_ioLRj4xUnk5mci6ateFRVe" : true
        }
      },
      "result": {
        "key": "APA91bEY678qaLUAB1tOPv...tZ9IG64H7b0KtOo-hSJdsoovmuRe2eCyoUeu4qs"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: tried adding the server key with the prefix but now the function returns `400` instead. Anyhow ... because of the security issue i will dump the client side case. Was wondering what could be a good architecture for doing it with `cloud functions`. Maybe have a pending operations table and listen to events on it ?

Comment: @John: Definitely doable with Cloud Functions.  I haven't had enough experience yet to recommend a design.  Sounds like your on the right track.

Comment: @John: I updated my answer.  I needed to learn about triggering Cloud Functions to perform server-side operations, so gave this a shot.  Maybe it will give you some ideas.  It can be improved, I'm sure.